# Concurrency Java example of Go

Tags: java, concurrency, go

I have below example of concurrency channels from [GoByExamples](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations)

Is there something equivalent in Java? I would have thought it would be much more verbose to implement the same thing.

```
// Basic sends and receives on channels are blocking.
// However, we can use `select` with a `default` clause to
// implement _non-blocking_ sends, receives, and even
// non-blocking multi-way `select`s.

package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)
    signals := make(chan bool)

    // Here's a non-blocking receive. If a value is
    // available on `messages` then `select` will take
    // the `<-messages` `case` with that value. If not
    // it will immediately take the `default` case.
    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message received")
    }

    // A non-blocking send works similarly.
    msg := "hi"
    select {
    case messages <- msg:
        fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no message sent")
    }

    // We can use multiple `case`s above the `default`
    // clause to implement a multi-way non-blocking
    // select. Here we attempt non-blocking receives
    // on both `messages` and `signals`.
    select {
    case msg := <-messages:
        fmt.Println("received message", msg)
    case sig := <-signals:
        fmt.Println("received signal", sig)
    default:
        fmt.Println("no activity")
    }
}
```

Comment: *Is there something equivalent in Java?* Yes. *I would have thought it would be much more verbose to implement the same thing.* Quite possibly. My hourly rates are really almost unbelievably reasonable if you'd like to find out for sure...

Comment: Technically yes, although I'm not going to do it :-) have a look at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-csp1/index.html (there are also parts 2 and 3, llinked from that doc) Also http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/ and wikipedia article on the same http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP .

Comment: This would be a good starting point:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561110/equivalent-of-golang-channel-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` statement ***is*** the reason to introduce concurrency at language syntax level in Go. Concurrent function call can (and usually done) be implemented on library level  with helper function like `spawn( function())` and channels just as data structures with mutex or lock in most other languages. But `select` statement can't.